# MSVC exhibits unexpected behavior while copying lambda using memcpy()

Tags: c++, lambda, msvc12

The reason I am asking this is because I need to store std::function in an in-house vector we have in company that internally does memcpy i.e. no copy/move operator.

This means all the element we can put in our container need to be trivially-copyable.

I have created a small program to replicate the issue. The following program seems to generate expected results when compiled with gcc but with MSVC it does not seem to work correctly-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

using VAR = void();
struct Abc
{
    std::function<VAR> fn;
};

struct Test{
    int i;
};

void openTest(const Test& a) noexcept
{
    cout<<"In Test"<<a.i<<endl;
};

void foo(Abc& abc, const Test& test)
{
    abc.fn = [test]() noexcept{ openTest(test);};
}
int main()
{
    Abc arr[2];

    for(int i=0;i<2;++i)
    {
        Abc abc;
        memset(&abc,0, sizeof(Abc));

        Test test{i*8+1};
        foo(abc,test);
        memcpy(&arr[i],&abc,sizeof(Abc));
        //To show the result **while** the array is populated
        arr[i].fn();
    }
    //To show the result **after** the array is populated
    for(int i=0;i<2;++i)
        arr[i].fn();
}
```

Code Executed here : https://godbolt.org/z/3fns5Kej3 
The execution results using **x86-64 gcc 12.2** -

```
In Test1
In Test9
In Test1
In Test9
```

The execution results using **x86 msvc v19.latest** -

```
In Test1
In Test9
In Test9
In Test9
```

Debugging the program, I see that during the second for loop iteration (i==1), the memcpy updates both the `arr[0].fn and arr[1].fn`.

Can someone explain why I am observing the incorrect behavior with MSCV?

Comment: You can't use `std::memcpy` to copy non-POD data structures.  As a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) is only defined to be an anonymous structure there are no guarantees that it is POD. [std::memcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) requires [TriviallyCopyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable)

Comment: I don't see [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) being described as trivially copyable. If I'm right, there is no correct behaviour because of UB

Comment: `Abc abc;   memset(&abc,0, sizeof(Abc));` --> `Abc abc {0};`

Comment: `memcpy(&arr[i],&abc,sizeof(Abc));`  -->  `arr[i]=abc;`

Comment: `static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable< Abc >::value, "cannot use memset/memcpy");`

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub